# Turtlesim Node not showing

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi people!
Hey I was following along the ROS2 tutorials (I have some ROS1 experience, just a little though) and found that the darn turtlesim is not creating a node. Neither are any of them services showing. However when looking with rqt, I can make service calls, as I can select them in the drop-down.

Further rqt_graph does show the node.

I have searched the forum and seems I'm not the first one to encounter this problem. However, none of the other posts did receive any replies. So hopefully this will get some attention, as it makes it hard for newbeis to follow the tutorials and it doesn't line-up.

Just to be clear, I did source the setup.bash (using born again sh) in every terminal.
ALso i did attach a screenshot, so you know I'm not insane (my psychiatrist insists I'm fine. Both of them!!)

ros2 (humble) on Ubuntu 22.04

[image: image description]
Thaaanks :-)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/406943/turtlesim-node-not-showing/) by [PointCloud](https://answers.ros.org/users/73699/pointcloud/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2022-09-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For anyone else trying to troubleshoot this issue when following along the tutorials. Please make sure that you set you ROS_DOMAIN properly.
As in the first few sections of the tutorials ROS_DOMAIN is mentioned to default to "0". So if any nodes, services, params, etc don't show up as expected, ensure you are in deed using the right ROS_DOMAIN.

One easy way is adding "export ROS_DOMAIN=0" to your ~/.bashrc at the bottom. Alternatively to editing the file, you can also just execute the following line in the terminal:

```
echo "export ROS_DOMAIN_ID=0" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Do one or the other, it won't hurt doing both but it would be silly :-)
Hope this helps someone

---

Originally posted by [PointCloud](https://answers.ros.org/users/73699/pointcloud/) with karma: 120 on 2022-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rakmo97](https://answers.ros.org/users/168994/rakmo97/) on 2023-08-08**:
Hello! Unfortunately, this didn't solve it for me. When I run `ros2 run turtlesim turtlesim_node`  and then `ros2 run turtlesim turtle_teleop_key` and finally `ros2 node list`, the only node that gets listed is `/teleop_turtle`.  I can't get the `/turtlesim` node to get listed, and this problem persists into params and services too.

The turtle in the popup window still responds to my key commands anyways, even though the `\turtlesim` node doesn't appear. Any ideas?

**Comment by [Rakmo97](https://answers.ros.org/users/168994/rakmo97/) on 2023-08-08**:
Apologies! Turns out restarting my computer solved the issue. Leaving all these comments here in case someone else runs into the same issues as me :)